# How to include a file in PHP that is above the public_html directory?

Tags: php, include

I need to include a file that's in /include/mysample.html.php

The file I am including it in is in /public_html/test/index.php

How can I reference it?

I tried

include '~/include/mysample.html.php' and it didn't work...

Comment: `~/` is an ASP thing. If you can't directly access it with `/include` (or a direct/relative path based on the server's environment and/or current file's location) it's probably a security restriction. Is this your own server, or a host you're using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `..` to go up a directory:

```
include '../../include/mysample.html.php';
```

Answer (score 0):

`~/` is a shell thing. The shell (aka bash, etc) interprets `~` to be the user's home directory. PHP is not going to do that, and instead will be looking for a directory named `~` in the current directory.

Your options:

- Use '..' to go up one directory.
- Use the absolute path to the directory you intend to include from.